# Sorting List of objects based on a field within a List in the List of objects

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator, comparable

I have two objects which have the following structure:

```
public class Event{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private List<Tags> tags;
}

public class Tags{
    private String tagName;
    private int rank;
}
```

I have a list of `Event` objects

```
 List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
```

I want to sort the events based on the rank in the `Tags` object.

For Example,

```
 Tags tag1 = new Tags("web", 1);
 Tags tag2 = new Tags("mobile", 7);
 List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<Tags>();
 tags.add(tag1);
 tags.add(tag2);
 Event event1 = new Event("test1",4242432, tags);

 Tags tag3 = new Tags("web", 2);
 Tags tag4 = new Tags("mobile", 8);
 List<Tags> tags1 = new ArrayList<Tags>();
 tags.add(tag3);
 tags.add(tag4);
 Event event2 = new Event("test2",546423, tags1);
```

So now I want to sort these two events based on the rank field within the `Tags` object. Since Tags is an `ArrayList` there can be multiple ranks, so I want to pass an argument, `tagName`, which will decide which ranks to compare within different `Tags` objects.

Comment: This is what the `Comparator` interface is for.  Implement a `Comparator<Event>` that returns -1, 0 or 1 when comparing two `Event` objects.  However, you have to decide what you mean by _"based on the rank field within the `Tags` object"_. Each `Event` contains potentially more than one `Tags` object.  Also, we're not going to write it for you.  Post what you have written so far.

Comment: Implement a custom sort algorithm.

Comment: @nikpon That is a quite bad advice in Java. Simply implementing Comparator is much more standard, probably less bugs, less tests.

Comment: @nikpon ok, probably less performant too, but that also requires tests. So I would still not suggest using custom sorting algorithm. This is not one of use cases of the O(1) sort algorithms.

Comment: @nikpon Here the problem is "How to write some code to compare two `Event` objects based on some `tagName`"? and not "How to sort list of `Event`?...... To perform any kind of sort, you should first have a way to compare two similar objects. Which sorting algo to use is a next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.lang.Comparator` interface.

```
public class EventComparator implements Comparator<Event> {

    private String tagName;

    public EventComparator(String tagName) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
        Tag t1 = getTag(e1, tagName); // getTag(...) returns the e1's tag with name 'tagName'
        Tag t2 = getTag(e2, tagName);

        // Ignoring null check for brevity
        if (t1.getRank() > t2.getRank())
            return 1;
        else if (t1.getRank() < t2.getRank())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Collections.sort(eventsList, new EventComparator("web"));
Collections.sort(eventsList, new EventComparator("mobile"));
```

Comment: Probably it might make sense prioritizing based on multiple tags too. But that is easy to implement.

Comment: That's the kind of answers that is really nice to see. Short, simple and to the point.